# Target Specific TypeScript Version on VSTS

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Just committed some code today to Visual Studio Team Services and the build is now compiling using TypeScript 2.4.  There are a bunch of errors that I do intend to fix, but is there any way of targeting 2.2 on Visual Studio Team Services until I fix the issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the answer to this is as simple as to add to the project a reference via NuGet for Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild changing the version to the one that you wish to use.